# Перестал работать мультикурсор в visual code studio

Tags: visual-studio-code

Перестал работать мультикурсор в visual studio code.

В настройках стоит сочетания клавиш ctr+alt+UpArrow и ctr+alt+DownArrow Но из этого ничего не работает

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение.
Почему-то работает сочетание клавиш ctrl+shisht+alt+upArrow, хотя в настройках стоит без шифта